# Select 4 random items from 3 random categories MySQL (and more)

Tags: php, mysql

i have specific request related to slideshow on test page here:
http://bybyweb.com/mealbook/

All the big pictures should be an image from a random category, with three recipes from that category listed in text.
Small thumbnails should show random recipes from any category.

So, there should be 3 random categories, 12 recipes from these categories (grouped by 4), AND 9 random recipes, unrelated to the rest...

Database scheme:
category: id, title, parent_id
category_to_recipe: id, rec_id, cat_id (this table is there because recipe can be in more than one category)
recipes: id, name, etc, etc...

this query:

```
SELECT category_recipe.rec_id, category_recipe.cat_id, recipes.name, recipes.url, recipes.main_image, categories.id, categories.title
FROM recipes, category_recipe, categories
WHERE categories.id
IN ( 10, 30, 64 )
AND category_recipe.cat_id = categories.id
AND category_recipe.rec_id = recipes.id
ORDER BY RAND( )
LIMIT 12
```

returns 12 random recipes from 3 categories, but i need 4 recipes per category...
I guess that there are more possible solutions, and i will probably need nested selects, or something....

Comment: Look at this, might give some input http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31495446/how-to-get-random-records-from-each-category-in-mysql/31496011?noredirect=1#comment50972156_31496011

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need `union all` for this:

```
SELECT cr.rec_id, cr.cat_id, r.name, r.url, r.main_image, c.id, c.title

from ((select cr.* from category_recipe where cat_id = 10 order by rand() limit 4
      ) union all
      (select cr.* from category_recipe where cat_id = 30 order by rand() limit 4
      ) union all
      (select cr.* from category_recipe where cat_id = 64 order by rand() limit 4
     ) cr join
     categories c
     on cr.cat_id = c.id join
     recipes r
     on cr.rec_id = r.id
```

In addition, you should use ANSI standard join syntax.  Your queries would also be more readable by using aliases.

Answer (score 0):

I would split that query for each of the 3 categories, I dont see a reason for making it so complicated, when those selects are extremely simple and will be blazing fast if speed is your issue.

Comment: yes i am little concerned regarding speed (because this is just one element on the page, and there will be a lot more db requests). So, you suggest that i select 3 random categories with first query, and then, when i get id's -> to make 3 separated queries for each recipe group (so i can get 4 recipes per category), and then one query for the rest of recipes (thumbnails)?